# How can I take good interior pictures (for selling the house)?

Tags: real-estate, interior

I'm about to put my house on the market, and I'd like to hear some tips for making the best possible photographs, specifically for this purpose.

Among things I should like to hear comments about are these:

- Use a fairly wide-angle lens
- Use low ISO and small aperture for sharpness and low noise
  (of course, this implies a tripod and long exposures)
- Tweak the colour temperature to make the interiors "glow"?
- Plus, of course, any other suggestions

FWIW, I'm using an EOS-M, probably with the 11-22mm lens (though I could also use one of the other two EF-M lenses), with DXO Optics Pro for post-processing.

I appreciate there isn't one single 'right' answer to this, but I couldn't find a button to turn it into a community wiki question. Anyone with the right combination of authority and opinion, please feel free to do so.

Comment: There is no longer a button to turn questions into community wiki because it's generally recognized across the network that community wiki doesn't work in most situations and should be used sparingly. Particularly, *this* sort of question is not a good fit for CW, because while there may not be one right answer, that's because there are many different answers and approaches, not a canonical shared answer. (Questions like the one about letters and codes used on lenses are what make sense and can work as CW.)

Comment: Also, definitely a duplicate. :)

Comment: Thanks and sorry. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No need to delete it. If someone finds this in a search, they'll be redirected to the earlier one, so it actually helps overall.

Answer (score 1):

photographyforrealestate.net has a lot of good information.

Probably the most important thing is to straighten your vertical lines. If you have a wall corner that's straight up and down in real life then it should be straight up and down in the picture; not curved or tilted as often happens with wide angle lenses that are raised too high and pointed downwards.

You'd also want to make sure that any lights that are on aren't blown out as they'll be distracting and if you can even the exposure of windows with the interior then it makes the interior space look larger and shows the view.

Comment: I'd suggest HDR for the windows+house combo.

Comment: If by HDR you mean tone mapping, I'd recommend against that as it can easily produce a look that isn't a good fit for real estate photography. It'd be easier and better to mask in the windows and lights.